# Regex doesn't work in internet explorer. the currency field work on chrome but I can not type any number in IE

Tags: javascript, html, regex, reactjs, react-native

this is my code. I try to make a currency field. it works on chrome but not internet explorer.

```
const handleOnChange = e => {
if (
  !"0.123456789".includes(e.nativeEvent.data) &&
  !["deleteContentForward", "deleteContentBackward"].includes(
    e.nativeEvent.inputType
  )
)
  return;`

let userInput = e.target.value;
userInput = userInput.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "");
//^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$m
const currency = prependDollarSign
  ? "$" + userInput.replace(/(\d)(?=\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?=\.))/g, "$1,")
  : userInput;

setFieldDisplayValue([name], currency);
setFieldTouched([name], true, false);
setFieldValue([name], userInput, true);};
```

Comment: IE does not support arrow functions. You must convert it to ES5, see https://medium.com/@SunnyB/how-to-convert-es6-into-es5-using-babel-1b533d31a169